# Tela do depurador Chrome para Flutter em branco

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Meu projeto em flutter executa no depurador Chrome mas nenhuma alteração visual feita é apresentada quando faço o Hot Reload, a tela fica toda branca e somente o titulo que consigo alterar. Alguém sabe me dizer oq pode estar acontecendo?

[image: Depurador Chrome rodando o projeto]

[image: restante do código]

Answer (score 0):

O método build da sua `MyHomePage` só está retornando um Scaffold com um Center como body. O widget Center por sí só não desenha nada na tela, ele somente centraliza o widget filho que ele recebe, e no caso nada está sendo passado no parâmetro child, então nada vai ser desenhado. E sua bottomNavigationBar está aparecendo ali, só que ela está branca, e como a backgroundColor do Scaffold por padrão é branco não vai aparecer direito, tenta mudar o backgroundColor do Scaffold ou a cor dos icones na sua `buildNavBarItem`.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).